# How do I control the modification trigger with Jquery

Tags: jquery

A section of a page is clickable when I move mouse over it. I want it to be grey and un-clickable if the class of this section is "completed". How do I do that?

I have some code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $session_rows = $(".coaching_page .user_session_info .session_info tr[session_id]");

    $session_rows.bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    });

    $(".created_column", $session_rows).add(".session_info_column", $session_rows).click(function() {
        $(window).attr("location", "<?php echo $progress_url ?>/session/" + $(this).parent().attr("session_id"));
    });

    $session_rows.find(".trash_column span.ui-icon-trash").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }).click(function() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Case?")) {
            $(window).attr("location", "<?php echo $remove_url ?>/session/" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("session_id"));
        }
    });
});
```

This is HTML part:

```
<table class="session_info">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="created_column">Created Date</td>
            <td class="session_info_column" colspan="2">Case Info</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($sessions as $session) : ?>
        <tr session_id="<?php echo $session->getId() ?>" class="completed">
            <td class="created_column"><?php echo $session->getDateTimeObject('created_at')->format('m/d/Y') ?></td>
            <td class="session_info_column">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info_label">Coach:</td>
                        <td><?php echo $session->getCoachUser()->getFullName() ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info_label"># Contacts:</td>
                        <td><?php echo $session->getCoachingReports()->count() ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info_label">Last Updated:</td>
                        <?php $edit = $session->getMostRecentReportEdit() ?>
                        <td><?php echo $edit ? $edit->getDateTimeObject('created_at')->format('m/d/Y') : '[No Edits Yet]' ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info_label">Total Minutes:</td>
                        <td><?php echo $session->calculateTotalMinutes() ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <?php if($sf_user->hasCredential(Attribute::COACHING_EDIT_ACCESS)) : ?>
            <td class="trash_column"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Remove</span></td>
            <?php endif ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just a little thought. you can replace `$(".created_column", $session_rows).add(".session_info_column", $session_rows).click(function() {` by `$(".created_column, .session_info_column", $session_rows).click(function() {`

Answer (score 1):

This may do the trick:

```
$('.completed').unbind('click').css('background-color','#999');
```

Comment: @roselan has a good point.  I'm not sure how you are adding the "completed" class to your element but you may need to use .live() or just include the snippet above with the code that is adding the "completed" class.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It doesn't work. I edited my question, please help me have a look. thanks

Comment: @AlexHu I don't see your code that adds the "completed" class.  Can you include that as well?

Answer (score 0):

as you bind on onlad, and you grey/complete on the fly, simply excluding .completed in the bind selector won't do.

you have two options: relpace .bind() with .live() or .delegate, and exclude .completed class in selector, or exclude completed in the bind, like that.

```
$session_rows.bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).not('.completed').toggleClass("highlighted");
    });

$(".created_column", $session_rows).not('.completed').add(".session_info_column", $session_rows).click(function() {
    $(window).attr("location", "<?php echo $progress_url ?>/session/" + $(this).parent().attr("session_id"));
});

$session_rows.find(".trash_column span.ui-icon-trash").not('.completed').bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
}).click(function() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Case?")) {
        $(window).attr("location", "<?php echo $remove_url ?>/session/" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("session_id"));
    }
});
```

edit: or use Allen Liu solution, which I did not think of :)

edit2: you can simply use the selector

```
$session_rows = $(/*.coaching_page .user_session_info*/ ".session_info tr[session_id]").not('.completed');
```

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJEnX/1/)

Comment: THanks so much for your reply. I tried but doesn't work. I will edit my question and add more info